# How to scale multiple overlay images

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay multiple images at a different intervals in a video file.
And i want to scale each image, i am able to do it for one image.
Could anyone please help me with scale option for other images as well,

`ffmpeg -i _2.mp4  -i gloves.png -i socks.png -i shoes.png -filter_complex 
"[1:v]scale=320:240 [ovrl], [0:v][ovrl]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,3,8)'[v1]; 
 [v1][2]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,6,8)'[v2];
 [v2][3]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,8,10)'[v3]" 
-map "[v3]"  -map 0:a -c:a copy outputVideo.mp4`

-Shoba

Comment: That does not seem like valid syntax. Between `[ovrl]` and `[0:v]` there should be a semicolon. You can just insert another scale filter like you did for `[1:v]`, then create another output and use that instead of `[2]` for the next overlay filter.

Comment: thank you, it worked.                                                                                    ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -i gloves.png -i socks.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:240 [ovrl]; [0:v][ovrl]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,3,8)'[v1];[2:v]scale=320:240 [ovrl1];[v1][ovrl1]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,15,20)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a -c:a copy outputVideo.mp4

Comment: If you want you can use the button below to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -i gloves.png -i socks.png -filter_complex 
"[1:v]scale=320:240 [ovrl]; [0:v][ovrl]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,3,8)'[v1];[2:v]scale=320:240 [ovrl1];[v1][ovrl1]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,15,20)'[v2]"
 -map "[v2]" -map 0:a -c:a copy outputVideo.mp4